# capture namespace'd global in lambda expression

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda

Why does the following code not compile in VS2010?

```
#include <functional>

namespace N
{
  struct A
  {
    A(std::function<void()> f)
    {
    }
  };

  struct B
  {
    void method()
    {
    }
  };

  B b;

  A a(
    [] () -> void
    {
      b.method(); // C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier
    }
  );
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh wow, need to put N::... But then why do I?

Comment: This should work. You don't need to capture globals.

Comment: I wonder if VS-2010, fully support such features

Comment: @P0W yes? I said it was fine.

Comment: @Simple oops I misread

Comment: @P0W [**Yes it does**](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) :)

Comment: Just for info, compilig with `g++ -std=c++11` in g++ 4.8.1 it works fine.